# Using File IO to create matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file called text.txt and I want to read its contents into a matrix. I am unsure how to do this.

The contents of the text file are:

```
!!!

@@@
```

I only want to keep the characters and not the newlines. is there any way to do this?

Comment: What code do you have so far? Exactly what is the problem with it? What do you mean "matrix" - lists? Something from `numpy`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have no code because I do not know how to approach it. I can read a file into a variable but I do not know how to put it in a 2D list

Comment: @novicecoder Is my answer what you mean?

Comment: @novicecoder then perhaps show the data in the variable, not what you have in the file, if reading data from the file isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    data = [list(line.strip()) for line in f if line.strip()]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> lines = ['!!!\n', '\n', '@@@\n']
>>> pprint([list(line.rstrip()) for line in f if line.strip()])
[['!', '!', '!'], 
 ['@', '@', '@']]
```

---

How it works (line by line):

so we take a line (iterating with `for line in f`):

```
'!!!\n'
```

we then strip it of trailing whitespace with `.rstrip()` (including newline).

```
'!!!'
```

then turn it into a `list` with `list()`

```
['!', '!', '!']
```

within the list comprehension so we do that for every line in the file.

However, we only bother with the line if it contains something other than whitespace- this is what the `if line.strip()` does.

Comment: This is very similar to what I am looking for can you please explain your code to me and how it works

Comment: @novicecoder There you go, I have added an explanation at the end.